# AWS Route53 GEO is sending less traffic overall

Tags: dns, geolocation, amazon-route53

**Overall issue:** When traffic is divided using geo-location routing total requests drops from 53k/sec to 47.5k/sec

---

I have 3 DCs configured in OVH (VIN-Virgina/HIL-Oregon/WAW-Warsaw),
DNS is using AWS Route53 and I can divide traffic in 2 ways,

1. Using weights (with VIN=2, HIL=2, and WAW=1 (WAW is a bit smaller)) or
2. Using geolocation (I tried geo-proximity as well before I had WAW, same results)

When I use the weights method - I get around 53k req/sec, but when I switch to geo-location it drops to around 47.5k req/sec.

**DNS configuration:**
Using GEO:

```
main.domain.com > CNAME: geo.domain.com
geo.domain.com > CNAME: (by geolocation)
  vin.domain.com > A: "IP of VIN location" (using failover)
  hil.domain.com > A: "IP of HIL location" (using failover)
  waw.domain.com > A: "IP of WAW location" (using failover)
```

Using weights:

```
main.domain.com > CNAME: ovh.domain.com
ovh.domain.com > CNAME: (by weight)
  vin.domain.com > A: "IP of VIN location" (using failover)
  hil.domain.com > A: "IP of HIL location" (using failover)
  waw.domain.com > A: "IP of WAW location" (using failover)
```

---

Geo Breakdown is as follows:
VIN: default
WAW: Africa, Asia, Europe
HIL: Austrailia, Canada, Mexico, Russia, US-Alaska, US-Arizona, US-California, US-Colorado, US-Hawaii, US-Idaho, US-Kansas, US-Montana, US-Nebraska, US-Nevada, US-New Mexico, US-North Dakota, US-Oklahoma, US-Oregon, US-South Dakota, US-Texas, US-Utah, US-Washington, US-Wyoming

---

There's not much I can think of trying,
I let it run on geo for a bit to confirm it's doesn't simply need time, but every time I use ovh.domain it works, and every time I use geo.domain it geos down.

Only results I can find on google is make sure to have a default location configured (which I do)